# Is it possible to find all visited links in the browser?

Tags: html, css, safari

This is the snippet from [this code](http://jsbin.com/udoJIti/1/edit):

```
<a href='www.apple.com'>apple</a>
<a href='www.google.com'>Google</a>
```

__

```
a{
    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(200,200,180,0.4);
    margin-bottom: 18px;
    line-height: 160%;

}

a:visited{
    background-color: red;
}
```

It applies `:visited` css to second hyperlink and if I change first hyperlink from www.apple.com to http://www.apple.com it applies `:visited` css to that also (strange?).

Why I am doing this is because one of the QA person says that one of the hyperlink in my page always shows as visited while he didn't visited the link. Even if we reset safari it still shows as visited. Unless we restart the mac it always says visited.

**Is it possible to show him the list of hyperlinks he visited**. *( It is not in browser history as well )*

Comment: What is so strange about http://www.apple.com being visited on a Mac?

Comment: strange is www.apple.com is not visited but http://www.apple.com is visited.   ( SO is stripping http:// from second link )

Comment: @BoltClock point is how to convince him that he have visited the link.

Comment: This is not a valid url `www.apple.com`, your website will refer this as a local path

Comment: Ok, can we find out list of all visited links in browser?

Answer (score 0):

I had checked your problem with some browsers, and at my side It is working fine, It means the person who is getting this problem need to be remove all web history from their browser.

Well It is also possible that your browser couldn't distinguish the links properly; well I'm mostly using Chrome, before some days I had also got a similar problem in which the links which are visited didn't change their color, So then to overcome the issue I had changed some user custom styles sheet which are stored at the Chrome local path folder.

Please make sure you cleared all your cache data. And if it is possible then create a new profile in the browser, as we do in Chrome.